# Term for the space of annihilators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, terminology, dual-spaces

I am learning about annihilators of vector spaces.

> Let $V$ be a vector space, and $W\subset V$. The set of all linear functionals $a$ in the dual space $V^*$ such that $\forall w\in W,\,a(w)=0$ is denoted $W^0$ and $a$ is called an annihilator of $W$. If $W$ is a proper subset of $V$, then $\exists a\neq0$.

I have two questions:

1. I know that $a$ is termed an annihilator, but the space $W^0$ is termed... the annihilation space? What is/are the formal term(s) (I am happy to hear about equivalents, even archaic ones)
2. How should one properly denote $W^0$? I am writing `W^0` but perhaps `W^\circ` is more appropriate - what is the correct way? Also, do any other notations exist?

Many thanks.

Comment: When I learnt these things, my professor wrote it as $W^0$. Moreover, we used to call $W^0$ the annihilator. I think I would just say $a$ is an element of the annihilator.

Comment: 1. $W^0$ is typically called the annihilator of $W$. 2. $W^0$ seems like a good notation. I've also seen it denoted $W^\perp$ (since the annihilator is the "dual" of the orthogonal complement of $W$ in a Hilbert space) but I think this is a much worse notation because of the other meaning.

Comment: Things in $W^0$ make things $0$, so $W^0$ makes sense but $W^\circ$ doesn't.